# Comparing a hashset with a text file present in raw folder in android

Tags: android, file-io, stringbuilder, hashset

I have a hashset and a text file in raw folder containing more than 80,000 words. 
I want to compare each element of the hashset with the words of the text file. But I am coming across a problem in this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{ 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lays=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lays);

TextView tvv=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                try {
                    tvv.setText(onCompare(MainActivity.this, sett));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                lays.addView(tvv); }
```

My method which compares is: onCompare 
And the file is: data.txt

```
    private String onCompare(Context context, HashSet set) throws IOException
{
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
    String ch=new String();
     StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<String> it=set.iterator();
    String s;
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

         s=it.next().toString();

        while((ch=br.readLine())!= null)
    {
        if(s.equals(ch))
        {
        text.append(ch);
        text.append('\n');
            break;
        }
    else continue;
    }


}
    return text.toString();
}
```

And I am printing this StringBuilder object in a textview named tvv in onCreate method. But nothing is getting printed in the textview. I think there is a problem in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there seems like an issue in your Condition. Try replacing `if(s.equals(ch))` with `if(s.contains(ch))`

```
while((ch = br.readLine())!= null) {
    if(s.contains(ch)) {
        text.append(ch);
        text.append('\n');
            break;
    }
}
```